# AnyDac aka FireDac cannot generate update query

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2012, firedac, anydac

I was using UniDac for a long time now and decided to move on to FireDac as it has good Asynch methods after moving on i saw that none of my data editing works anymore it gives me an error:

> [FireDAC][Phys]-330. Cannot generate update query. Update table undefined.

What I am trying to do here is i have a TFDStoredProc component who gets all the data from the database and lets me edit it, with unidac I could easily edit the data without any problem like this:

```
StoredProc.Edit;
StoredProcCreatedID.Value := SomeValue;
StoredProc.Post;
```

and it worked, but with AnyDac it doesn't, I tried specifying manually the UpdateTable which leads to another problem:

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'CreatedID'.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 FireDac 8.0 and stored procedures for getting back results any ideas?

**P.S.**

The query looks like this

```sql
SELECT 
    CreatedBy as CreatedID,
    usr.UserName as CreatedBy
FROM 
    Sales
LEFT JOIN 
    Users usr ON usr.ID = Sales.CreatedBy
```

it looks like the FireDac update builder doesn't recognize the aliases on the fields, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the query without the aliases?

Comment: no can do the aliases play a very big role in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i figured out what was the issue, it seems that if you specify a alias in the query for a field the **Origin** property will be set to the alias and not the real field i downloaded **CNPack** a must have for a delphi developer also its free, ran the component selector and changed all my aliased fields to their real fields and it works, but this is still a big issue in FireDac component because it doesnt recognize the aliased fields, lets hope it will be fixed in the future as to specify for every query what table it should update and what fields that just allot of work if you are migrating from a big project in my case 220+ stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

See the TRANSACTION ISOLATION level of the database. Probably it is set to READ UNCOMMITTED